# Copying data from excel to SQL Database VB.NET

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, datagridview

I want to use a excel file to import data at any given time.

I have the database created and I need to import the data to it.

I was able to import the data to a DataGridView, but now I can't import to the database.

The code that I have right now to import from the DGV to the Database is

```
    Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


    command.CommandText = "InsertDataIntoDevicesLDL"

    command.Parameters.Add("@SN", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdClass", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdManu", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdModel", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@PartNum", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdClt", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdWh", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Slot", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdLoc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@IdSts", SqlDbType.VarChar)

    MyConnection.Open()
    command.Connection = MyConnection


    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        command.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        command.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        command.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        command.Parameters(3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        command.Parameters(4).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        command.Parameters(5).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        command.Parameters(6).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
        command.Parameters(7).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
        command.Parameters(8).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value
        command.Parameters(9).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

End Sub
```

And I have the procedure InsertDataIntoDevicesLDL as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataIntoDevicesLDL]

@SN         NCHAR (10), 
@IdClass    INT,        
@IdManu     INT,       
@IdModel    INT,    
@PartNum    NCHAR (10),  
@OrdNum     NCHAR (10), 
@ATCode     NCHAR (10),  
@Ticket     NCHAR (10),
@CreDate    DATETIME , 
@ExpeDate   DATETIME,   
@OBS        NCHAR (200), 
@IdClt      INT,        
@IdWh       INT,       
@Slot       NCHAR (10),
@IdLoc      INT,     
@IdSts      INT,
@IdLdl      INT      

AS

BEGIN

Insert into Equipamento (SerialNumber, ID_CLASS, ID_Manufacturer, ID_Model,ProductNumber, OrderNumber, ATCode, Ticket, CreationDate, ExpeditionDate, Observations, ID_CLT,ID_WH, Slot, ID_loc, ID_STS, ID_LDL)
    Values (@SN, @IdClass, @IdManu, @IdModel, @PartNum, @OrdNum, @ATCode, @Ticket, @CreDate, @ExpeDate, @OBS, @IdClt, @IdWh, @Slot, @IdLoc, @IdSts, @IdLdl )

END
```

So my question is.

How do I import it.

Right now I'm getting the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'InsertDataIntoDevicesLDL' expects parameter '@SN', which was not supplied.'
```

Comment: Why don't you write the insert-command directly into the CommandText? You defined all parameters, that would be an easier way I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the parameter doesnt get a value passed.

Try something like:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connection)

 Dim command As New SqlCommand("[dbo].[InsertDataIntoDevicesLDL]", connection)
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
 command.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@sn",Cstr(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value))
 command .ExecuteNonQuery()
 Next

End Using
```

Comment: I have to do the
`command.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@sn",Cstr(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value))`  to all of the fields, right?

Comment: I have add the line for each field I have on the DB, and I'm getting this error now:

`The conversion of type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid. '`

On the excel file the field is empty, but it is normal. There are some fields that are not going to be always filled. 

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Try it without the conversion to string. it expect a parameter from type object         command.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@sn",DataGridView1.Row‌s(i).Cells(0).Value)

Comment: I've made a few changes and its almost working now. It writes on the data base, but is retrieving the error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
But only after the information is passed to the database.  Any help on that?

Comment: Its too much to put in here: 

I left only the `FOR...NEXT` I have posted, with the changes that you have suggested before. I took the conversion  to string off.  

And the error changed: Now its showing :

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'InsertDataIntoDeviceLDL' expects parameter '@SN'. wich was not supplied.`

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The DGV had the adding option available, so i had 181 records on the excel file, but 182 rows on the DGV, and the last row was completely empty, and it was causing that error.